# Mysql query check 2 column

Tags: mysql

So i got  5 columns ID, name, country, payment 1 and payment 2
is there a way that i can say like 
`Select * from payment where payment1 = payment2` ?

and also when payment1 isnt the same as payment 2 ? so something like this

`Select * from payment where payment1 != payment2` ?

Comment: Have you tried your first query before posting?

Comment: Select * from payment where payment1 = payment2... is that giving you an error?

Comment: Have you tried your second query before posting?

Answer (score 0):

You meant

> Select * from payment where payment1 <> payment2

Comment: in MySQL dialect, `!=` is the same as `<>`